# How to get Youtube "Auto-generated CC" with Node.Js using Youtube Api?

Tags: node.js, youtube-api

How would one go about getting Auto generated subtitles for Youtube videos uploaded from my own account, in XML or srt form.

If there isn't a way using Youtube-api, is there any other method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to refer with this [tutorial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@joegesualdo/get-youtube-subtitles-node) to get the subtitles of a youtube video.

Here's an example which returns `Promise` that passes the resulting subtitles.

```
var getYoutubeSubtitles = require('@joegesualdo/get-youtube-subtitles-node');

let videoId = 'q_q61B-DyPk'

getYoutubeSubtitles(videoId, {type: 'nonauto'})
.then(subtitles => {
  console.log(subtitles)
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

Additional references:

- [youtube-dl](https://github.com/przemyslawpluta/node-youtube-dl)
- [Get subtitles from Youtube in SRT format](https://www.garysieling.com/blog/get-subtitles-youtube-srt-format)

Comment: I think the answer is no.